# Meteor: Using an HTML Template to add to the DOM.

Tags: meteor

I'm building an app with Meteor.js, and I've got a form where I would like to be able to allow the user to add a new row to the form when they click a button (`button.addExperience`). I'm using an HTML Template to populate each row of the form.

How would I have the template (`experienceRow`) rendered each time the user clicks the button?

See example code below:

```
<body>
  <form>       
   {{> experienceRow }}
  </form>
  <button class="addExperience">Add Experience</button>
</body>

<template name="experienceRow">
  <div id={{experienceNumber}} class='experienceRow'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" value="" class="name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="address" value="" class="address">
    <input type="text" placeholder="phone" value="" class="phone">
  </div>        
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an `each` block along with a reactive variable. That variable could be a `ReactiveVar`, a session varaible, a local collection, etc. Here's an example implementation using a `ReactiveVar` to hold an array of ids:

**html**

```html
<body>
  {{> experienceForm }}
</body>

<template name="experienceForm">
  <form>
    {{#each experienceIds}}
      {{> experienceRow }}
    {{/each}}
  </form>
  <button class="addExperience">Add Experience</button>
</template>

<template name="experienceRow">
  <div id={{this}} class='experienceRow'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" value="" class="name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="address" value="" class="address">
    <input type="text" placeholder="phone" value="" class="phone">
  </div>
</template>
```

**js**

```js
Template.experienceForm.onCreated(function() {
  this.experienceIds = new ReactiveVar(Random.id());
});

Template.experienceForm.helpers({
  experienceIds: function() {
    return Template.instance().experienceIds.get();
  }
});

Template.experienceForm.events({
  'click .addExperience': function(e, template) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ids = template.experienceIds.get();
    ids.push(Random.id());
    template.experienceIds.set(ids);
  }
});
```

Note that you'll need to `meteor add reactive-var` for this to work.

Recommended reading: [scoped reactivity](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity).

Comment: If you want to persist the values in each row across sessions and users then you'll want to insert them into a *collection* instead of a reactive variable.